# Spring Boot: When to call remote service?

Tags: spring-boot

I have serveral microservices communicating with each other.
For general configuration I use Spring Cloud Config which works well.
Some of the services need to access database resources of a legacy system. So they need to know where the database (databases in a multi-tenant environment) is located and which credentials to use.

Using Spring Cloud Config I see two possibilities:

1. application.properties: This would expose the db settings to all services. That´s no option.
2. my-crazy-service.properties: This would work fine but I would have to configure any service which needs db access. Doesn´t scale well.

So my idea is to implement another microservice which is responsible for any connection infomation. This service exposes a rest endpoint using spring-data-rest.
In case Service A wants to use the legacy db it can call the new service and ask for the required data.

Now I wonder when the best time is to request the connection info from the remote service. 
On startup of each microservice? Where should such startup code be located?
In general where should initialization stuff be done?

Comment: If all your applications load the same `application.properties` you have done something wrong already (imho).

Comment: Am I missunderstanding something. As I understand application.properties is provided to any service requesting config from the config server. So what´s wrong with distributing general settings through this mechanism?
But that was not my question. I would like to know where the best place is to run some startup/init code.